# How can I isolate (or filter) a part of a string in several columns at the same time?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, filter

I have a data frame with bacteria families from with all their OTUs (phylum, order, family...).

[image]

The data frame is large and I would like the name of each column to be only the last part of each string. The one that starts with "f___"

For example

[image]

I tried some methods in R (like dplyr::filter or filter(str_detect))and also separating columns in Excel and could not get what I wanted. I don't do it manually because it's too many columns.

Comment: In the past new users were prevented from posting images. Your question is a good example for why I think that was that was a good idea.It would have allowed a popup to be displayed that would explain why. See this answer in the Meta section: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557  and search SO for "how to create a great reproducible example in R"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`df` being your dataframe, you could use `rename_with` from package `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
    rename_with(
        ## your renaming function (see ?gsub for help on
        ## replacing with search patterns (regular expressions):
        ~ gsub('.*;f___(.*)$', '\\1', .x),
        ## column selection (see ?dplyr::select for handy shortcuts)
        cols = everything()
    )
```

the `.x` in the replacement formula `~ etc.` represents the variable argument to the replacement function, in this case the 'old' column name. You'll encounter this 'dot-something' pattern frequently in `tidyverse` packages.

Comment: I tried it but it did not generate any change in the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

microbiota <- read_csv("Tablas/nivel5-familia_clean.csv")
colnames(microbiota) <- gsub(colnames(microbiota),pattern = '.*f__', replacement = "")

I solve it like this.